# How to get the update fileds in oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stu_trigger BEFORE UPDATE OF stuname 
            OR INSERT ON T_STU 
                FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO stu_tmp(stuid , stuname, stusex) 
                VALUES( :new.stuid, :new.stuname, :new.stusex);
            END;
```

I have a trigger like above,and now I want to get the update fields(stuname) by sql

```
Select * From all_triggers where table_name = 'T_STU';
```

This sql can select the trigger info ,but not have the fields info.

How to get the fields info by sql?

Comment: `select * from all_trigger_cols where table_name = 'T_STU'`?

Comment: yeah,thanks very much